# Angular2 RxJs: simple take() from http returned observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I simply try to `.take(5)` from an http returned observable:

```
this.dataObservable = this._service.getData()
                                   .take(5);
```

and use it in HTML like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of dataObservable | async">
```

This works. But I get **all** the records, I just want 5. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

In the _service I return the http observable:

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
  url = '/getData';
  this._data = this._http.get(url)
    .map(response => this.extractData(response));
  return this._data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `.take(5)` will take 5 emits of your Observable, not 5 elements of that containing data.

You should limit it to 5 in your `.map` function.

Or `.subscribe` to that observable and in that function you will limit incoming data in store it in a local variable which will be bound to your template.

```
getData(): Observable<any[]> { // returns an array, right??
  url = '/getData';
  this._data = this._http.get(url)
    .map(response => this.extractData(response));
  return this._data;
}
```

// in your component

```
this.yourService.getData().subscribe(
   dataArray => this.data = dataArray.slice(0, 5),
   err => console.log(err)
);
```

`this.data` will be bound to your template.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Could you expand how to limit the response in the .map with equivalent of .take what I'm trying to achieve?